# Lottery class with arraylist that has no duplicate numbers AND can't fall out of range

Tags: java, arraylist

I am in an intro to java class. I am relatively new to this programming language. I have to make a lottery class, in which the users must enter a number between 1-9 and it cannot be duplicate. For this I made an array list. Here is what I have so far:

```
public class Lottery {

private int lotteryNumber[] = new int[5];
private ArrayList<Integer> userLotteryPicks = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);

public Lottery() {

    Random myRan = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < lotteryNumber.length; i++) {
        lotteryNumber[i] = myRan.nextInt(9) + 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if ((lotteryNumber[i] == (lotteryNumber[j])) && (i != j)) {
                i = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

public void getUserPicks() {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int userPicks = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter your 5 lucky numbers for the lottery: ");
        userPicks = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (userPicks < 10 && userPicks > 0) {
            userLotteryPicks.add(userPicks);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not a valid entry. "
                    + "Make sure the number is between 1-9 "
                    + "Enter your 5 numbers again \n");
            i = 0;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if ((userLotteryPicks.get(i) == (userLotteryPicks.get(j))) && (i != j)) {
                i = 0;
                System.out.println("You put an invalid entry. No duplicates allowed"
                        + " please start over. \n ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The getUserPicks is the method I am having trouble with. If the user enters a duplicate the first time, the next loop it says anything they enter is a duplicate. Thank you for any help.

Comment: You could simplify `getUserPicks()` by looping `while (userLotteryPicks.size() < 5)` (just a single loop) and within the loop, inspecting whether `userLotteryPicks.contains(userPicks)` and then deciding whether the number is a duplicate or not.

Comment: You might want to check whether the arraylist contains the user's pick *before* you put it there. It'll simplify the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the HashSet instead of ArrayList for storing the number. Sets does not allow duplicates. You need not to start over again, for any wrong input. Check the code below.

```
// Change this initialization to Set instead of ArrayList
private Set<Integer> userLotteryPicks = new HashSet<Integer>(5);

public void getUserPicks() {
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  int userPicks = 0;
  System.out.println("Enter your 5 lucky numbers for the lottery: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    userPicks = keyboard.nextInt();

    boolean unique = false;
    if (userPicks < 10 && userPicks > 0) {
      unique = userLotteryPicks.add(userPicks);   //if duplicate, then it return false.
    } else {
      System.out.println("Not a valid entry. "
          + "Make sure the number is between 1-9.");
      i--;  // for wrong inputs, decrease the counter by again, instead of start over again.
      continue;
    }
    if (!unique) {
      System.out.println("You put an invalid entry. No duplicates allowed. Enter the number again.");
      i--;  // for wrong inputs, decrease the counter by again, instead of start over again.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. I had not been taught sets yet. Thank you!

Comment: @cdeleon_305 You can always use the `userLotteryPicks.contains(userPicks)` method from `ArrayList`, before adding the number to list. Add the number only, if is not present in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one more easiest form,

```
public void getUserPicks(){
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int userPicks = 0;

        while (hs.size() < 5) {
            System.out.println("Enter your 5 lucky numbers for the lottery: ");
            userPicks = keyboard.nextInt();

            if (userPicks < 10 && userPicks > 0) {
                if(hs.add(userPicks)){ // it return true if Unique value enter otherwise duplicate won't entered

                }else{
                    System.out.println("You put an invalid entry. No duplicates allowed"
                            + " please start over. \n ");
                }
            }else{
                    System.out.println("Not a valid entry. "
                            + "Make sure the number is between 1-9 "
                            + "Enter your 5 numbers again \n");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("User Entered Values : " + hs);


}
```

Comment: How does the     'hs.add(userPicks)' determine if there are duplicates? Thanks for your help! I want to fully understand the code

Comment: Integer class has override 2-method, i.e. hashcode() and equals(). so all the magic is because of that methods. in stead of Integer you can use your custom class then in that case you have to override hashcode() and equals to resolve duplication. However Integer class is in-built class and it's already covered it.

Comment: @cdeleon_305 duplicate allows but in what case ? i probably guess duplicate allows while you are using you custom class instead of Integer here.